# Resetting the permissions on an Access 2007 mdb file

Tags: permissions, microsoft-access

Background story : I need to modify the structure of an access database (add some columns, modify some).

Problem : Someone belonging to the Admins group thought it would be a good idea to remove the "Administer" permission to the Admins group. I don't need to recover a password, I have the passwords. The problem is that no user have the permission to modify, or give permission to other user/groups.

Am I doomed? If not, how can I do this?

Comment: That's the proper way to secure the design of a Jet data store, so it wasn't something that was a bad idea. However, the secured workgroup file is supposed to travel with the developer's copy of the database. You can get programs to crack Jet user-level security, but I don't know where or how much they cost, nor how well they work. If you really don't have the proper workgroup file, that may be your only option.

Comment: You're talking about a ".mdw" file here, right? I do have one, I use it with "Start MSACCESS [MyDataFile].mdb /wrkgrp:[SecurityFile].mdw", and even with this, it seems like this user don't have the permissions.

Comment: In a really secured database, the production workgroup file will NOT include the administrative user that has permissions to edit everything (not the user named "admin"), so that's to be expected. You need to find a copy of that workgroup file that has an administrative user included. For what it's worth, I've never bothered to remove the administrative user from the production workgroup file, but it's technically the way you're supposed to do things to fully secure your app.